# Non-constant condition error only shown on some compilers with lambda

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda, compiler-errors, language-lawyer

I have the following snippet which has an object with a compile-time value:

```
template <int V>
struct Value
{
  constexpr Value() = default;
  constexpr int value() const  { return V; }
};

int main()
{
  Value<1> v;
  static_assert(v.value(), ""); // OK

  auto l = [=]()
  {
    static_assert(v.value(), ""); // Error
  };

  (void)l;
}
```

The problem is in the `static_assert` within the lambda. It passes on gcc 6.4, 10.1 but fails on 7.1 and 8.1. The first assert (outside of the lamda) passes on all of them. If changed to `constexpr Value<1> v;`, it starts passing on 7.1 but not 8.1. I was wondering why this is happening.

Demo:
https://godbolt.org/z/4z7vdKGMq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gcc 8.1 contained a compiler bug that prevented lambda captures from being constexpr:
[Bug 86429 - [8 Regression] lambda capture breaks constexpr-ness](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86429)

It was fixed in 8.4, but not backported to previous versions. So gcc versions 8.1 - 8.3 still contain this bug, preventing the captured `v` from being treated as constexpr.

---

For 7.1 i'm not 100% sure since i didn't manage to find a bug for it; but given that it rejects some constructs even with `constexpr` my guess would be that it is a precursor-bug to the 8.1 one that just happend to remain unnoticed.

It fails with exactly the same error message - `'__closure' is not a constant expression` - if an explicit capture clause is used:

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/qYovGEq5n)

```cpp
constexpr Value<1> v;
static_assert(v.value(),""); // OK

auto l = [v]() {
    static_assert(v.value(),""); // OK (Error in 7.1)
};

auto l2 = [&v]() {
    static_assert(v.value(),""); // OK (Error in 7.1)
};

auto l3 = [=]() {
    static_assert(v.value(),""); // OK
};

auto l4 = [&]() {
    static_assert(v.value(),""); // OK
};
```